# Some output data is missing in pandas dataframe (python), while importing csv files

Tags: python, pandas

[This the code and image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJvBv.png)
[Output: after 4 it jumps to 403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCBcB.png)
Here the output is displaying till 4 rows and then jumps to the 403rd row, don't know whats happening.

I am new to pandas, please help me!!!

Comment: Nothing is missing.

Comment: This is just for display to avoid flooding the screen with large datasets.